# "Pelle de neige" vs "pelle à neige"

Tags: sens, prépositions, à, de, groupe-nominal

What is the difference between "*une pelle de neige*" and "*une pelle à neige*"? Which word is correct to refer to a "snow shovel" that we use in winter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A ***pelle à neige*** means a shovel designed to be used to move snow while a ***pelle de neige*** would mean the quantity of snow that it contains (a shovelful of snow). The latter is better transcripted by ***Une pelletée de neige***.

Comment: Actually, "pelle de neige" would be a shovel made of snow. I've never heard it used instead of "pelletée de neige".

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur An hypothetical shovel made of snow would more be a "pelle en neige". "Pelle de neige" is a lazy way, at least in France, to say the more literary "pelletée de neige".